# The validity of infinite many Conformal Field Theories on the Fermi surface

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, conformal-field-theory, fermi-liquids, tomonaga-luttinger-liquid

The naive $2$-dimensional **Fermi sea** in $k$-space (with a convex structure and positive Gaussian curvature, some nice properties, etc) in $2+1$-dimensional spacetime may be viewed as an infinite collection of the $1$-dimensional in k-space **chiral Conformal Field Theory** perturbed around from the Fermi surface. For example, based on the picture of [this Ref](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/72499).

More generally, the naive $d$-dimensional Fermi surface in $k$-space (with convex structure and positive Gaussian curvature, some nice properties, etc) in $d+1$-dimensional spacetime may be viewed as an infinite collection of the $(d-1)$-dimensional chiral Conformal Field Theory perturbed around from the Fermi surface.

I suppose that this scheme works for non-interacting fermions or Landau Fermi liquid theory with good quasi-particle description (where quasi-particle is dressed by the renormalized effect on effective mass, spectral weight, from interactions). However, we know there are phenomena beyond Landau Fermi liquid theory, such as (1) 1+1 d **Luttinger liquid theory**, or the (2) higher dimensional (2+1d above) where Landau Fermi liquid theory breaks down: e.g. **critical Fermi surface** and **non-Fermi liquid theory**.

**Does the infinite many Conformal Field Theory on the Fermi surface picture still hold its validity for those exotic cases?**

Comment: I also suppose that the validity of infinite many Conformal Field Theories on the Fermi surface relies on that the Fermi energy $E_F$ is much larger than the energy excitation scales, such as the debye frequency $\omega_D$. So $E_F \gg \omega_D$.

Comment: I suppose that the Fermi surface of Landau Fermi liquid theory can be viewed as some infinite many free Conformal Field Theories on the Fermi surface. But perhaps certain non-Landau Fermi surface can be viewed as some infinite many "**interacting**" Conformal Field Theories?